Why /sys/devices/.../product_serial sometimes reads as garbage?
Service reads sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_serial somewhere at start and generally it contains some typical hex number of ten digits (e.g. 01212302C5) with newline. However sometimes the content is not parsable to string - bytes in hex are f8 6a 32 6d 0a and I can't figure out why and how this happens. The last 0a seems to hint it still was supposed to be text. Happens generally in CI but I'm not sure may containerized environment somehow be the reason of the issue.
What could be the reason of such a queer behavior?

Does "sometimes" mean "with certain devices/containers/whatevers"? Or does it mean "sometimes happens even on the exact situation that previously provided a good value"?

While the DMI standard specifies that strings should be displayable characters (p. 17), and that serial numbers are 64 byte long strings (or 63, after they somehow manage to mess up v2.0 by requiring that in addition to a length field, the strings also need to be null-byte terminated) (and note that they also mess up unicode support, but that's sadly typical for a standard this old):
Vendors put stuff in fields. Sad truth of life. Unless you're positively certain that the value should be something else than '\xf8\x6a\x32\x6d\x0a' == 'øj2m\n' (DMI specifies ISO-8859-1), you don't have a problem with Linux, but typical firmware vendor code quality.
If you know for a fact that the field is different, then there might be a problem with the DMI communication. I'd call the Linux DMI implementation "mature", i.e., it'd not be clear to me whether the problem is hardware, firmware or the kernel side, and I'd probably start by tracing out the communication between kernel and firmware to see whether the string I'm looking for appears somewhere else in a response.

Thank you! I'm not positively sure this is wrong, so what you are saying defnintely make sense. A bit queer why this may happen on CI (one worker different than others?) - but I guess I should address this to some of our infrastructure engineers. Thank you very much for thorough explanation!

Hm, CI might be running on a hypervisor that doesn't really give you proper access?
